# iOS: Drawing a CGImage into a subclass of CALayer during custom property animation in correct resolution

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, cgimage, retina-display

I'm at the end of my wisdom...

I have a view which should display an animated circular section which is pre-rendered and available as png files (both retina and non-retina versions, correctly named; pie_p_000.png vs. pie_p_000@2x.png). This section should be animated according the change to some percentage value within the app. So I made a subclass of UIView which has a custom CALayer within its layer hierarchy. The plan is to implement a custom animatable property for the CALayer subclass and change pictures in the overridden method drawInContext:. So far so good, the plan worked and the animation is shown when I change the percentage value using the function setPercentageWithFloat: of the view (full source below).
The thing is: I really don't know why my iPhone4 always presents the low-res image. I tried already playing around with scale factors, but that didn't help. Either the images are presented in the right size and low-res or the images are presented double size.
Overriding display: and setting the contents property directly has the effect that the animation doesn't appear (during the animation no image is presented); after the animation time the final image is presented. In this case the correct resolution image is presented.

Btw: the following code is not very sophisticated in error-handling, flexibility and elegance yet as it is an attempt just to get that thing running ;) - so the image is still presented flipped and so on...

I hope that somebody has a hint for me.
Thanks

The view:

```
#import "ScrollBarView.h"
#import "ScrollBarLayer.h"

@implementation ScrollBarView

@synthesize sbl;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setImagesWithName:(NSString*)imageName {
    ScrollBarLayer *ssbl = [[ScrollBarLayer alloc] init];
    ssbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [ssbl setImagesWithName:imageName];
    [self.layer addSublayer:ssbl];

    self.sbl = ssbl;

    [ssbl release];
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.sbl = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setPercentageWithFloat:(CGFloat)perc {
    if(perc > 1.0){
        perc = 1.0;
    } else if(perc < 0) {
        perc = 0;
    }

    [self.sbl setPercentage:perc];

    CABasicAnimation* ba = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"percentage"];
    ba.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    ba.duration = 0.8;
    ba.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:perc];
    [self.sbl addAnimation:ba forKey:nil];
}
@end
```

The View can be configured to work with different images (using the function setImagesWithName:) using different names (theName). Within this method the View adds the ScrollBarLayer to its layer property.

The Layer:

```
#import "ScrollBarLayer.h"

@implementation ScrollBarLayer

@synthesize filename;
@dynamic percentage;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setImagesWithName:(NSString*)imageName {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    self.percentage = 0;
    self.filename = imageName;
}

+ (BOOL) needsDisplayForKey:(NSString*)key {
    if([key isEqualToString:@"percentage"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    int imageIdx = (int)roundf((float)199 * self.percentage);
    NSString *thisfilename = [self.filename stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d.png", i+1]];
    UIImage* c = [UIImage imageNamed:thisfilename];
    CGImageRef img = [c CGImage];
    CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(img), CGImageGetHeight(img));

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(sz.width, sz.height), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height), img);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.pictures = nil;
    self.filename = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would need light on this.

I think that the issue is between points and pixels... I think that you should check if the device has a retina display, and if so, you should replace the CGContextDrawImage(...) CGRect (in second parameter) for one with half width and height.

```
#define IS_RETINA_DISPLAY() ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00)

...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(sz.width, sz.height), NO, 0.0);

if (IS_RETINA_DISPLAY())
{
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width/2.0f, sz.height/2.0f), img);
} else
{
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height), img);
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
...
```

But I'm not sure this gill give you a "smooth" result...